# Show that the map $\phi:C\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ is an embedding.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry, partial-derivative

> Let $C$ be the cone $\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}:x^2+y^2=z^2,z\geq 0$. Let $g:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be any differentiable map. Show that the map $\phi:C\rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$, $\phi(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})=(x,y,g(x,y))$ is an embedding.

First of all we must prove that $\phi$ is differentiable. I wanted to say that partial derivatives are continuous to show it. But, how could I define them since I have $\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$ instead of $z$?

Comment: calculate the jacobian $J\phi$ and check the matrix-rank

Comment: To define Jacobian I need partials. I have clearly stated that I found difficult in defining partials here.

Comment: you have a composition $(x,y)\to(x,y,z)$ for the cone and $(x,y,z)\to(x,y,g(x,y))$ for $\phi$

Comment: But $(x,y)→(x,y,z)$ for the cone is not differentiable at (0,0)$

Comment: What's the context of this question? $C$ is not a smooth submanifold of $\mathbb R^3$, so the only way the question can make sense is if (a) you're only supposed to to show that it's a _topological_ embedding, or (b) the question is somehow assuming some nonstandard smooth structure on $C$.